# Advantages of std::for_each over for loop

Tags: c++, stl, foreach, coding-style

Are there any advantages of [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) over `for` loop? To me, `std::for_each` only seems to hinder the readability of code. Why do then some coding standards recommend its use?

Comment: `std::for_each` when used with `boost.lambda` or `boost.bind` can often improve readability

Comment: The question and accepted answer are from 2010. For a more uptodate answer (from 2018), see here:https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/03/30/is-stdfor_each-obsolete/

Answer (score 206, accepted):

The nice thing with [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for_loop) (previously called C++0x), is that this tiresome debate will be settled.

I mean, no one in their right mind, who wants to iterate over a whole collection, will still use this

```
for(auto it = collection.begin(); it != collection.end() ; ++it)
{
   foo(*it);
}
```

Or this

```
for_each(collection.begin(), collection.end(), [](Element& e)
{
   foo(e);
});
```

when the *range-based `for` loop* syntax is available:

```
for(Element& e : collection)
{
   foo(e);
}
```

This kind of syntax has been available in Java and C# for some time now, and actually there are way more `foreach` loops than classical `for` loops in every recent Java or C# code I saw.

Comment: Actually, a foreach loop with scoop has been available for a long time in boost, and I still want to iterate with for_each and a lambda function.

Comment: The assumption about wanting the entire container range isn't part of the question, so this is only a partial answer.

Comment: Note that looping over an element is probably not the only thing you want to do, so it can be a good idea to use for_each just so that you learn about find / partition / copy_replace_if and the others, which is what a lot for loops actually do.

Comment: Range-for is nice, except when you actually need the iterator (then there's no way of getting to it).

Comment: It is very likely that `Element & e` has to be `const Element & e`

Comment: @Damon: I saw an outdirection_range adapter somewhere in boost::range once (can't find it now). That could be used to range--for-loop iterate over the iterators.

Comment: @Macke: I'm not sure that would work with standard range-for since it's defined in a way so no iterator that you could pull out of your hat is available. Semantics have that you only ever get to see the dereferenced iterator.

Comment: @Damon: Define a range/container adaptor whose begin()/end() returns an iterator whose value_type is the container's underlying iterator, so when dereferenced, you get the iterator itself, and that will be the inferred type when auto:ing the loop variable. It's certainly doable as I've used it occasionally at a previous job.

Comment: I'd not use even `Element & e` as  `auto & e` (or `auto const &e`) looks better. I'd use `Element const e` (without reference) when I want implicit conversion, say when the source is a collection of different types, and I want them to convert into `Element`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  "Are there any advantages of std::for_each over for loop?"

Comment: This is plain wrong. Using a range for, most of the time is a violation of the correct level of abstraction. https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/03/30/is-stdfor_each-obsolete/ And I'm not even finished, about `Element&`: hard-type, `auto` and cv-qualification are not trivial to decide in that construct. c.f. the explanation why by Stephan Lavavej https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/01/n3853

Comment: what if you want to iterate over just a subset of your container? you can't use range-for directly using only `std::` functionality (unless it is `for (auto& e : boost::make_iterator_range(begin, middle) { ... }`), whereas you can do it with `std::for_each(begin, middle, ...)`.

Comment: I tried the last example, with the range based for-loop, and it ran twice as fast as the other examples above. I'm compiling with VC++ x64 in release mode. Why is this the case? Is it because the iterator overhead is bypassed? Will this performance gain be seen compiling with gcc?

Comment: @aj.toulan: what last example? repeated how many times? show reproducible code & context, or such anecdotes are meaningless.

Comment: My bad @underscore_d. I'm sure I did 500, 1000 and 10000 iterations of a summation or something similar, it's been a while. I said in my comment it was the range-based example. Sorry I don't have the code sample, I also don't have easy access to a VC++ compiler anymore as I've switched to linux. In my comment, I wanted to see if anyone had noticed the same performance increase that I did. I guess that's not the case, but if you're interested you can experiment on your own. Seems you're more interested in attempting to ridicule me instead. So if you want another stab let's see it, lol.

Comment: @aj.toulan I'm not trying to ridicule you, just expect evidence for claims. Sorry if it came across otherwise.

Comment: @underscore_d sorry I got so defensive. I see what you're saying. I wanted to share that I saw it run faster, not saying it is faster in all cases. I will definitely give instructions to replicate next time.

Answer (score 61):

Here are some reasons:

1. It seems to hinder readability just because you're not used to it and/or not using the right tools around it to make it really easy. (see boost::range and boost::bind/boost::lambda for helpers. Many of these will go into C++0x and make for_each and related functions more useful.)
2. It allows you to write an algorithm on top of for_each that works with any iterator.
3. It reduces the chance of stupid typing bugs.
4. It also opens your mind to the rest of the STL-algorithms, like `find_if`, `sort`, `replace`, etc and these won't look so strange anymore. This can be a huge win.

**Update 1:**

Most importantly, it helps you go beyond `for_each` vs. for-loops like that's all there is, and look at the other STL-alogs, like find / sort / partition / copy_replace_if, parallel execution .. or whatever.

A lot of processing can be written very concisely using "the rest" of for_each's siblings, but if all you do is to write a for-loop with various internal logic, then you'll never learn how to use those, and you'll end up inventing the wheel over and over.

And (the soon-to-be available range-style for_each) + lambdas:

```
for_each(monsters, [](auto& m) { m.think(); });
```

is IMO more readable than:

```
for (auto i = monsters.begin(); i != monsters.end(); ++i) {
    i->think();
}
```

Also this:

```
for_each(bananas, [&](auto& b) { my_monkey.eat(b); );
```

Is more concise than:

```
for (auto i = bananas.begin(); i != bananas.end(); ++i) {
    my_monkey->eat(*i);
}
```

But new range based for is probably the best:

```
 for (auto& b : bananas)
     my_monkey.eat(b);
```

But the for_each could be useful, especially if you have several functions to call in order but need to run each method for all objects before next... but maybe that's just me. ;)

**Update 2**: I've written my own one-liner wrappers of stl-algos that work with ranges instead of pair of iterators. boost::range_ex, once released, will include that and maybe it will be there in C++0x too?

Comment: +1, several functions or nested types: `outer_class::inner_class::iterator` or they are template arguments: `typename std::vector<T>::iterator`... the for construct itself can run into a many line construct in itself

Comment: (btw: the `for_each` in the second example is incorrect (should be `for_each( bananas.begin(), bananas.end(),...`

Comment: I've written wrappers that use ranges instead of two iterators. These will be available later (see range_ex) but everyone should have them anyway. (Added update on that.)

Comment: Parallel processing support is no. 1 reason here. We can add implementation to use cuda/gpu for heterogeneous-parallel computing.

Comment: I like the example with `boost::bind`, I guess we could replace it with `std::bind`. Do we gain any performance by `for_each` with `bind`?

Answer (score 27):

`for_each` is more generic. You can use it to iterate over any type of container (by passing in the begin/end iterators). You can potentially swap out containers underneath a function which uses `for_each` without having to update the iteration code. You need to consider that there are other containers in the world than `std::vector` and plain old C arrays to see the advantages of `for_each`.

The major drawback of `for_each` is that it takes a functor, so the syntax is clunky. This is fixed in C++11 (formerly C++0x) with the introduction of lambdas:

```
std::vector<int> container;
...
std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), [](int& i){
    i+= 10;
});
```

This will not look weird to you in 3 years.

Comment: @Marcus: that will be the ranged-for construct and the syntax will not read 'for_each' in itself: `for ( int v : int_vector ) {` (even if it can be simulated today with BOOST_FOREACH)

Comment: @David: I'm referring to the general addition of range-based functions (so you can use ranges with all these for_each, copy, remove_if, etc etc functions),

Comment: Why is it not possible to write: `std::for_each(container, [](int& i){ ... });`. I mean why is one forced to write container twice?

Comment: @Giorgio that is not "writting the container twice". The range `[begin, end)` is specified to `std::for_each` by giving the `begin` and the `end` iterators.

Comment: @freitass: Writing the container once as in my previous comment could default to using the begin end iterator without calling them explicitly. Most language that provide higher-order functions on collections (Ruby, Scala, ...) write something like `container.each { ... }` without mentioning begin and end iterators. I find it a bit redundant that I have to specify the end iterator all the time.

Comment: @Giorgio: Sorry. I think the way I read your question in the first place made me perceive it that way.

Answer (score 18):

Personally, any time I'd need to go out of my way to use `std::for_each` (write special-purpose functors / complicated `boost::lambda`s), I find `BOOST_FOREACH` and C++0x's range-based for clearer:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Monster* m, monsters) {
     if (m->has_plan()) 
         m->act();
}
```

vs

```
std::for_each(monsters.begin(), monsters.end(), 
  if_then(bind(&Monster::has_plan, _1), 
    bind(&Monster::act, _1)));
```

Answer (score 12):

its very subjective,  some will say that using `for_each`  will make the code *more* readable, as it allows to treat different collections with the same conventions. 
`for_each` itslef is implemented as a loop

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
  Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f)
  {
    for ( ; first!=last; ++first ) f(*first);
    return f;
  }
```

so its up to you to choose what is right for you.

Answer (score 11):

Like many of the algorithm functions, an initial reaction is to think it's more unreadable to use foreach than a loop. It's been a topic of many flame wars.

Once you get used to the idiom you may find it useful. One obvious advantage is that it forces the coder to separate the inner contents of the loop from the actual iteration functionality. (OK, I think it's an advantage. Other's say you're just chopping up the code with no real benifit).

One other advantage is that when I see foreach, I *know* that either every item will be processed or an exception will be thrown.

A *for* loop allows several options for terminating the loop. You can let the loop run its full course, or you can use the *break* keyword to explicitly jump out of the loop, or use the *return* keyword to exit the entire function mid-loop. In contrast, *foreach* does not allow these options, and this makes it more readable. You can just glance at the function name and you know the full nature of the iteration.

Here's an example of a confusing *for* loop:

```
for(std::vector<widget>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
{
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // Imagine a page of code here by programmers who don't refactor
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   if(widget->Cost < calculatedAmountSofar)
   {
        break;
   }
   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // And then some more code added by a stressed out juniour developer
   // *#&$*)#$&#(#)$#(*$&#(&*^$#(*$#)($*#(&$^#($*&#)$(#&*$&#*$#*)$(#*
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   for(std::vector<widgetPart>::iterator ip = widget.GetParts().begin(); ip != widget.GetParts().end(); ++ip)
   {
      if(ip->IsBroken())
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You make a good point, but your motivation example isn't entirely fair. When you use `std::for_each()` in the old standard (that of the time of this post) you have to use a named functor, which encourages readability as you say and prohibits breaking out of the loop prematurely. But then the equivalent `for` loop has nothing but a function call, and that too prohibits breaking out prematurely. But other than that I think you made an excellent point in saying that `std::for_each()` _enforces_ going through the entire range.

Answer (score 11):

You're mostly correct: most of the time, `std::for_each` is a net loss. I'd go so far as to compare `for_each` to `goto`. `goto` provides the most versatile flow-control possible -- you can use it to implement virtually any other control structure you can imagine. That very versatility, however, means that seeing a `goto` in isolation tells you virtually *nothing* about what's it's intended to do in this situation. As a result, almost nobody in their right mind uses `goto` except as a last resort.

Among the standard algorithms, `for_each` is much the same way -- it can be used to implement virtually anything, which means that seeing `for_each` tells you virtually nothing about what it's being used for in this situation. Unfortunately, people's attitude toward `for_each` is about where their attitude toward `goto` was in (say) 1970 or so -- a *few* people had caught onto the fact that it should be used only as a last resort, but many still consider it the primary algorithm, and rarely if ever use any other. The vast majority of the time, even a quick glance would reveal that one of the alternatives was drastically superior.

Just for example, I'm pretty sure I've lost track of how many times I've seen people writing code to print out the contents of a collection using `for_each`. Based on posts I've seen, this may well be the single most common use of `for_each`. They end up with something like:

```
class XXX { 
// ...
public:
     std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os) { return os << "my data\n"; }
};
```

And their post is asking about what combination of `bind1st`, `mem_fun`, etc. they need to make something like:

```
std::vector<XXX> coll;

std::for_each(coll.begin(), coll.end(), XXX::print);
```

work, and print out the elements of `coll`. If it really did work exactly as I've written it there, it would be mediocre, but it doesn't -- and by the time you've gotten it to work, it's difficult to find those few bits of code related to what's going on among the pieces that hold it together.

Fortunately, there is a much better way. Add a normal stream inserter overload for XXX:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream *os, XXX const &x) { 
   return x.print(os);
}
```

and use `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(coll.begin(), coll.end(), std::ostream_iterator<XXX>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

That does work -- and takes virtually no work at all to figure out that it prints the contents of `coll` to `std::cout`.

Comment: +1, There's one mistake though. In first example it should be `boost::mem_fn(&XXX::print)` rather than `XXX::print`

Comment: That's why I said that example won't work, and they're posting asking for help to get it work (oh, and you also need to bind `std::cout` as its argument for it to work).

Comment: Although it's generally a good answer, the question is not about for_each's value or its value compared to other std algorithms, but about its value compared to a for loop. You may think of it in cases where no other std algorithm applies. Would you then use a for_each or a for loop? Think about it and whatever you come up with, that should've been your answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau: There's always a fine line between answering the question exactly as asked, and trying to provide useful information. The direct answer to exactly the questions he asked would be "Probably not. Who knows?", but would be too useless to be worth the bother. At the same time going too far afield (e.g., recommending Haskell instead of any of the above) isn't likely to be of much use either.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I should add that IMO, your downvote is *thoroughly* unwarranted. If we consistently followed the narrow view you seem to be taking of what constitutes a helpful answer, it looks to me like your reputation would be 0 (and only escape being negative because they site doesn't allow it).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Since it didn't answer the question in any way, I stand to my down-vote. Nothing against providing additional information, but at least some words on the actual question would have sufficed for separating it from a (though good, but also quite long) comment.

Comment: @ChristianRau: How do you figure that "...most of the time, std::for_each is a net loss" doesn't address the question of whether std::for_each provides an advantage?

Answer (score 9):

The advantage of writing functional for beeing more readable, might not show up when `for(...)` and `for_each(...`).

If you utilize all algorithms in functional.h, instead of using for-loops, the code gets a lot more readable;

```
iterator longest_tree = std::max_element(forest.begin(), forest.end(), ...);
iterator first_leaf_tree = std::find_if(forest.begin(), forest.end(), ...);
std::transform(forest.begin(), forest.end(), firewood.begin(), ...);
std::for_each(forest.begin(), forest.end(), make_plywood);
```

is *much* more readable than;

```
Forest::iterator longest_tree = it.begin();
for (Forest::const_iterator it = forest.begin(); it != forest.end(); ++it{
   if (*it > *longest_tree) {
     longest_tree = it;
   }
}

Forest::iterator leaf_tree = it.begin();
for (Forest::const_iterator it = forest.begin(); it != forest.end(); ++it{
   if (it->type() == LEAF_TREE) {
     leaf_tree  = it;
     break;
   }
}

for (Forest::const_iterator it = forest.begin(), jt = firewood.begin(); 
     it != forest.end(); 
     it++, jt++) {
          *jt = boost::transformtowood(*it);
    }

for (Forest::const_iterator it = forest.begin(); it != forest.end(); ++it{
    std::makeplywood(*it);
}
```

And that is what I think is so nice, generalize the for-loops to one line functions =)

Comment: Maybe my opinion sucks, but I prefer to read the structured code, cpp11's for(:) makes second bit much easier to read.

Answer (score 8):

Easy: `for_each` is useful when you already have a function to handle every array item, so you don't have to write a lambda. Certainly, this

```
for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), a_item_handler);
```

is better than

```
for(auto& item: a) {
    a_item_handler(a);
}
```

Also, ranged `for` loop only iterates over whole containers from start to end, whilst `for_each` is more flexible.

Comment: Why is for_each better in this case?

I think ranged for is better because I like being able to step through code with a debugger rather than dropping a breakpoint in some function used in many places.

Comment: Stepping through a loop with a debugger is only an option when the collection is small. Normally you would set a conditional breakpoint inside handler function.

Answer (score 4):

The `for_each` loop is meant to hide the iterators (detail of how a loop is implemented) from the user code and define clear semantics on the operation: each element will be iterated exactly once.

The problem with readability in the current standard is that it requires a functor as the last argument instead of a block of code, so in many cases you must write specific functor type for it. That turns into less readable code as functor objects cannot be defined in-place (local classes defined within a function cannot be used as template arguments) and the implementation of the loop must be moved away from the actual loop.

```
struct myfunctor {
   void operator()( int arg1 ) { code }
};
void apply( std::vector<int> const & v ) {
   // code
   std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), myfunctor() );
   // more code
}
```

Note that if you want to perform an specific operation on each object, you can use `std::mem_fn`, or `boost::bind` (`std::bind` in the next standard), or `boost::lambda` (lambdas in the next standard) to make it simpler:

```
void function( int value );
void apply( std::vector<X> const & v ) {
   // code
   std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind( function, _1 ) );
   // code
}
```

Which is not less readable and more compact than the hand rolled version if you do have function/method to call in place. The implementation could provide other implementations of the `for_each` loop (think parallel processing).

The upcoming standard takes care of some of the shortcomings in different ways, it will allow for locally defined classes as arguments to templates:

```
void apply( std::vector<int> const & v ) {
   // code
   struct myfunctor {
      void operator()( int ) { code }
   };
   std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), myfunctor() );
   // code
}
```

Improving the locality of code: when you browse you see what it is doing right there. As a matter of fact, you don't even need to use the class syntax to define the functor, but use a lambda right there:

```
void apply( std::vector<int> const & v ) {
   // code
   std::for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), 
      []( int ) { // code } );
   // code
}
```

Even if for the case of `for_each` there will be an specific construct that will make it more natural:

```
void apply( std::vector<int> const & v ) {
   // code
   for ( int i : v ) {
      // code
   }
   // code
}
```

I tend to mix the `for_each` construct with hand rolled loops. When only a call to an existing function or method is what I need (`for_each( v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind( &Type::update, _1 ) )`) I go for the `for_each` construct that takes away from the code a lot of boiler plate iterator stuff. When I need something more complex and I cannot implement a functor just a couple of lines above the actual use, I roll my own loop (keeps the operation in place). In non-critical sections of code I might go with BOOST_FOREACH (a co-worker got me into it)

Answer (score 3):

Aside from readability and performance, one aspect commonly overlooked is consistency. There are many ways to implement a for (or while) loop over iterators, from:

```
for (C::iterator iter = c.begin(); iter != c.end(); iter++) {
    do_something(*iter);
}
```

to:

```
C::iterator iter = c.begin();
C::iterator end = c.end();
while (iter != end) {
    do_something(*iter);
    ++iter;
}
```

with many examples in between at varying levels of efficiency and bug potential.

Using for_each, however, enforces consistency by abstracting away the loop:

```
for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), do_something);
```

The only thing you have to worry about now is: do you implement the loop body as function, a functor, or a lambda using Boost or C++0x features?  Personally, I'd rather worry about that than how to implement or read a random for/while loop.

Answer (score 3):

I used to dislike `std::for_each` and thought that without lambda, it was done utterly wrong. However I did change my mind some time ago, and now I actually love it. And I think it even improves readability, and makes it easier to test your code in a TDD way.

The `std::for_each` algorithm can be read as **do something with all elements in range**, which *can* improve readability. Say the action that you want to perform is 20 lines long, and the function where the action is performed is also about 20 lines long. That would make a function 40 lines long with a conventional for loop, and only about 20 with `std::for_each`, thus likely easier to comprehend.

Functors for `std::for_each` are more likely to be more generic, and thus reusable, e.g:

```
struct DeleteElement
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(const T *ptr)
    {
        delete ptr;
    }
};
```

And in the code you'd only have a one-liner like `std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), DeleteElement())` which is slightly better IMO than an explicit loop.

All of those functors are normally easier to get under unit tests than an explicit for loop in the middle of a long function, and that alone is already a big win for me.

`std::for_each` is also generally more reliable, as you're less likely to make a mistake with range.

And lastly, compiler might produce slightly better code for `std::for_each` than for certain types of hand-crafted for loop, as it (for_each) *always* looks the same for compiler, and compiler writers can put all of their knowledge, to make it as good as they can.

Same applies to other std algorithms like `find_if`, `transform` etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you frequently use other algorithms from the STL, there are several advantages to `for_each`:

1. It will often be simpler and less error prone than a for loop, partly because you'll be used to functions with this interface, and partly because it actually is a little more concise in many cases.
2. Although a range-based for loop can be even simpler, it is less flexible (as noted by Adrian McCarthy, it iterates over a whole container).
3. Unlike a traditional for loop, `for_each` forces you to write code that will work for any input iterator. Being restricted in this way can actually be a good thing because:

   1. You might actually need to adapt the code to work for a different container later.
   2. At the beginning, it might teach you something and/or change your habits for the better.
   3. Even if you would always write for loops which are perfectly equivalent, other people that modify the same code might not do this without being prompted to use `for_each`.
4. Using `for_each` sometimes makes it more obvious that you can use a more specific STL function to do the same thing. (As in Jerry Coffin's example; it's not necessarily the case that `for_each` is the best option, but a for loop is not the only alternative.)

Answer (score 3):

With C++11 and two simple templates, you can write

```
        for ( auto x: range(v1+4,v1+6) ) {
                x*=2;
                cout<< x <<' ';
        }
```

as a replacement for `for_each` or a loop. Why choose it boils down to brevity and safety, there's no chance of error in an expression that's not there.

For me, `for_each` was always better on the same grounds when the loop body is already a functor, and I'll take any advantage I can get.

You still use the three-expression `for`, but now when you see one you know there's something to understand there, it's not boilerplate.  I *hate* boilerplate.  I resent its existence.  It's not real code, there's nothing to learn by reading it, it's just one more thing that needs checking.  The mental effort can be measured by how easy it is to get rusty at checking it.

The templates are

```
template<typename iter>
struct range_ { 
                iter begin() {return __beg;}    iter end(){return __end;}
            range_(iter const&beg,iter const&end) : __beg(beg),__end(end) {}
            iter __beg, __end;
};

template<typename iter>
range_<iter> range(iter const &begin, iter const &end)
    { return range_<iter>(begin,end); }
```

Answer (score 2):

`for` is for loop that can iterate each element or every third etc. `for_each` is for iterating only each element. It is clear from its name. So it is more clear what you are intending to do in your code.

Comment: not if you pass it an iterator which advances by 3 with each `++`. Unusual maybe, but so is a for-loop doing the same.

Comment: In that case maybe it'll better to use `transform` to not to confuse someone.

Answer (score 2):

`for_each` allow us to implement [Fork-Join pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model) . Other than that it supports [fluent-interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

## fork-join pattern

We can add implementation `gpu::for_each` to use cuda/gpu for heterogeneous-parallel computing by calling the lambda task in multiple workers.

```
gpu::for_each(users.begin(),users.end(),update_summary);
// all summary is complete now
// go access the user-summary here.
```

And `gpu::for_each` may wait for the workers work on all the lambda-tasks to finish before executing the next statements.

## fluent-interface

It allow us to write human-readable code in concise manner.

```
accounts::erase(std::remove_if(accounts.begin(),accounts.end(),used_this_year));
std::for_each(accounts.begin(),accounts.end(),mark_dormant);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you'll have to **iterate over the whole collection**. Therefore I suggest you write your own for_each() variant, taking only 2 parameters. This will allow you to rewrite [Terry Mahaffey's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047414/advantages-of-stdforeach-over-for-loop/2047440#2047440) as:

```
for_each(container, [](int& i) {
    i += 10;
});
```

I think this is indeed more readable than a for loop. However, this requires the C++0x compiler extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I find for_each to be bad for readability. The concept is a good one but c++ makes it very hard to write readable, at least for me. c++0x lamda expressions will help. I really like the idea of lamdas. However on first glance I think the syntax is very ugly and I'm not 100% sure I'll ever get used to it. Maybe in 5 years I'll have got used to it and not give it a second thought, but maybe not. Time will tell :)

I prefer to use

```
vector<thing>::iterator istart = container.begin();
vector<thing>::iterator iend = container.end();
for(vector<thing>::iterator i = istart; i != iend; ++i) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

I find an explicit for loop clearer to read and explicity using named variables for the start and end iterators reduces the clutter in the for loop.

Of course cases vary, this is just what I usually find best.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good reasons in other answers but all seem to forget that
`for_each` allows you to use reverse or pretty much any custom iterator when for loop always starts with `begin()` iterator.

Example with reverse iterator:

```
std::list<int> l {1,2,3};
std::for_each(l.rbegin(), l.rend(), [](auto o){std::cout<<o;});
```

Example with some custom tree iterator:

```
SomeCustomTree<int> a{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
auto node = a.find(4);
std::for_each(node.breadthFirstBegin(), node.breadthFirstEnd(), [](auto o){std::cout<<o;});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the iterator be a call to a function that is performed on each iteration through the loop.

See here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

Comment: Link-only posts do not make good answers, and anyway, where in that link does it show anything resembling a callable iterator? I'm pretty sure that concept just doesn't make sense. Maybe you were just summarising what `for_each` does, in which case, it doesn't answer the question about its advantages.

Answer (score 0):

For loop can  break; 
I dont want to be a parrot for Herb Sutter so here is the link to his presentation:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-835T
Be sure to read the comments also :)

Answer (score 0):

#### `std::for_each` is great when you *don't* have a range.

For example, consider `std::istream_iterator`:

```
using Iter = std::istream_iterator<int>;

for (Iter i(str); i != Iter(); ++i) {
    f(*i);
}
```

It has no container, so you can't easily use a `for (auto &&item: ...)` loop, but you can do:

```
std::for_each(Iter(str), Iter(), [](int item)
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of C++2x, you can empower your `std::for_each` with ranges `std::ranges::for_each` and pipe all complex and nested loops into nice pipe-delemited and readable loops