# Is there any basis for this alternative 'for' loop syntax?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I came across [a set of slides](https://www.fefe.de/c++/c%2B%2B-talk.pdf) for a <strike>rant</strike> talk on C++. There were some interesting tidbits here and there, but slide 8 stood out to me. Its contents were, approximately:

> ### Ever-changing styles
>
> #### Old and busted:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
> ```
>
> #### New hotness:
>
> ```
> for (int i(0); i != n; ++i)
> ```

I'd never seen a `for` loop using the second form before, so the claim that it was the "New hotness" interested me. I can see some rationale for it:

1. Direct initialization using a constructor vs copy initialization
2. `!=` could be faster in hardware than `<`
3. `++i` doesn't require the compiler to keep the old value of `i` around, which is what `i++` would do.

I'd imagine that this is premature optimization, though, as modern optimizing compilers would compile the two down to the same instructions; if anything, the latter is worse because it isn't a "normal" `for` loop. Using `!=` instead of `<` is also suspicious to me, because it makes the loop semantically different than the original version, and can lead to some rare, but interesting, bugs.

Was there any point where the "New hotness" version of the `for` loop was popular? Is there any reason to use that version these days (2016+), e.g. unusual loop variable types?

Comment: `++i` is better than `i++` not for any arcane reasons of second-guessing the compiler, but because it's what you mean. Write code that does what you mean, not some other code that happens to solve your problem as a side effect. But that's been true since 1972, so I wouldn't call that "new hotness".

Comment: I'm not sure the rationale for #2 applies to any practical HW implementation...

Comment: Your "new hotness" compiles in [c++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e04f0b96a103c06), I would disregard the content of those slides.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Why is `++i` more "what you mean" than `i++` in this situation?

Comment: actually we can simply write `int i(10);`. This is not only made for loops.

Comment: A similar argument can be made for the predicate. Use `<` when the ordering of integers is material to the algorithm. Otherwise, if all you want is a sentinel that signals the end of the iteration, then `!=` is more appropriate, since it makes fewer assumptions about the details and concentrates on the underlying logic. The benefit is that the very thought process is now "portable", since it applies to a much more general concept of iteration. Again, the technicalities haven't changed since 1972, but the experience with generality and code reuse has.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Because all you mean is to increment the variable; you don't mean to obtain its previous value.

Comment: @KerrekSB - But I don't mean to obtain either its previous *or* its new value - all I'm interested in is the side-effect of incrementing ;)

Comment: This is not so much about `++` as it is about a combination of `++` and `!=`. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth This seems to be a case of: I consider i++ to be the default, and ++i an optimization vs I consider ++i to be the default and i++ to be syntactic sugar for when I also need the original value.

Comment: To provide a (flippant) answer to the actual question - I suspect the author is merely providing a (flippant) strawman example to support his thesis that C++ style has evolved significantly.

Comment: To make the code even more "modern", you may also use uniformal initialization: `int i{0};` instead of `int i(0);`. Such a form has many advantages: [1](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax), [2](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/), [3](https://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/), but the `for` loop initialization seems to be the least sensible place for it.

Comment: The slides are from 2007. C++ has changed considerably, and the way that C++ is (or should be) programmed is very different from the old times. I would disregard the talk and look at some newer material instead.

Comment: #2 argument is nonsense IMHO: Any CPU I know that has some sort of `cmp` instruction will set and reset both zero and carry flag with no additional effort whatsoever - Thus "equal" and "less than" (or, their negation) are tested with the very same instruction

Comment: @KerrekSB That's a good point. Don't think that is what was on the author's mind, but still a good reason to not bother with such trivial things.

Comment: @Borgleader I wasn't expecting it to fail compilation; it's just the claim/style that was interesting. And yeah, the i++ vs ++i default thing definitely is factoring in here; haven't quite cleaned out the Java from my C++ (and C, in this case) style.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yeah, that's what I was thinking too, but in the absence of a recording I was hoping that he'd actually have some sort of rationale besides "It looks funny"

Comment: @Jens Yeah, it's slightly out of date. I'm not trying to use it as a reference; I'm just wondering where the author was coming from

Comment: Isn't the new hotness "no raw for loops"?

Comment: @manni66 Those slides are pretty old, so the "new" it is referring to isn't very new

Comment: This is the same guy who delivered [a massive rant](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30475) on GCC's treating signed overflow as undefined. A healthy helping of salt is needed.

Comment: @T.C.: In 1988, the term "C" described a language whose semantics were, essentially, "On platforms which are similar to the PDP-11 except for built-in types' representations and alignment requirements, behave like the language Dennis Ritchie invented on the PDP-11".  On platforms which differed from the PDP-11 in other ways, it would have been unclear--prior to the C standard--when an implementation should be expected to do whatever is necessary to emulate the PDP-11 behavior, and when it shouldn't, but platforms that were fundamentally similar to the PDP-11 (i.e. the vast majority...

Comment: ...of implementations that were current in 1988, and the even vaster majority of implementations that are current today) could cheaply support many useful behaviors which would be expensive to support on other platforms.  For years afterward, on most platforms, the term "C" meant the *superset* of the language that existed previously and the language defined by the Committee.  The language would be vastly more useful if behaviors that had been defined on most platforms prior to C89 were recognized as being defined, by default, on such platforms except when explicitly waived.

Comment: @T.C.: Having a mode where an overflowed integer quantity may arbitrarily compare larger or smaller than any other integer would facilitate optimizations *if* a cast to the integer type were required to wrap the result into range (so `x+y > x` could be replaced with `y>0`, but `(int)(x+y) > x` would have to perform the arithmetic and examine the lower 32/64/whatever bits as a two's-complement signed quantity.  Forcing programmers to avoid overflow at all costs, however, leads to code which is less efficient than would be possible with the above semantics.

Comment: @T.C.: I think a fundamental problem is that some people today assume the authors of the Standard were trying to balance programmer friendliness with optimization. They were doing nothing of the sort. Their primary objective was that if an existing compiler for some platform--no matter how obscure--could perform some task with a certain level of performance, a C89 compiler should be able to do just as well. If some obscure platform benefited from treating something as UB, even if 99% of other platforms defined it, then the proper thing to do was have the Standard impose no requirements but...

Comment: ...figure that if implementations where it was sensible to define the behavior did so, without having to be ordered to, before the Standard was published, they would likewise continue to do so, without having to be ordered to, afterward.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

1. > Direct initialization using a constructor vs copy initialization

   These are exactly identical for `int`s and will generate identical code. Use whichever one you prefer to read or what your code policies are, etc.
2. > `!=` could be faster in hardware than `<`

   The generated code won't actually be `i < n` vs `i != n`, it'll be like `i - n < 0` vs `i - n == 0`. That is, you'll get a `jle` in the first case and a `je` in the second case. All the `jcc` instructions have identical performance (see [instruction set reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) and [optionization reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html), which just list all the `jcc` instructions together as having throughput 0.5).

   Which is better? For `int`s, probably doesn't matter performance-wise.

   Strictly safer to do `<` in case you want to skip elements in the middle, since then you don't have to worry about ending up with an infinite/undefined loop. But just write the condition that makes the most sense to write with the loop that you're writing. Also take a look at [dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39494757/2069064).
3. > `++i` doesn't require the compiler to keep the old value of `i` around, which is what `i++` would do.

   Yeah that's nonsense. If your compiler can't tell that you don't need the old value and just rewrite the `i++` to `++i`, then get a new compiler. Those definitely will compile to the same code with identical performance.

   That said, it's a good guideline to just use the right thing. You want to increment `i`, so that's `++i`. Only use post-increment when you need to use post-increment. Full stop.

---

That said, the real "new hotness" would definitely be:

```
for (int i : range(n)) { ... }
```

Comment: @Nawaz lol you deleted your post like 1s before I was about to upvote it...

Comment: For your proposed newest hotness. How about `auto i`? What type would `i` be if auto was used?

Comment: 1 -- Right, I know they compile down to the same thing for primitives, but I was wondering whether there was an advantage for any other types, or whether the compiler can still figure things out because of the context.

Comment: And I should be ashamed of myself for missing that reasoning for 2. I finished a low-level programming class a few semesters ago...

Comment: And I've never actually seen range-for used like that. That's something I'll need to be using from here on out.

Comment: @awksp They're always identical, except in cases where the constructor is explicit in which case one will compile and the other won't.

Comment: @Barry Not quite. `struct Evil { explicit Evil(int); Evil(double); }; Evil e1(1) /* int */, e2 = 1 /* double */;`

Comment: @T.C. Yeah this is one of those places where I do not like that direct-init and copy-init are different.

Comment: What's this `range` thing? A quick Google search doesn't turn it up.

Comment: `++i` vs `i++` used to be a useful performance difference with something more complex - such as an stl iterator.  We performance profiled a piece of software back in the day and found it was spending 80% of its time in iterator copy constructors because of `i++`!  But maybe even that's not the case these days.

Comment: @user2357112: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3648965/5771399 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach#C.2B.2B

Comment: @v7d8dpo4: Range-based for loops are a feature, sure, but `range(n)`? That's not any standard C++ feature I'm aware of. It looks more like what you'd see in Python.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes it's not in the standard library, but it's easily implementable to do the same thing you'd get from python.

Answer (score 22):

You are right about optimizing compilers and prefix vs. postfix `++` operator. It does not matter for an `int`, but it matters more when you use iterators.

The second portion of your question is more interesting:

> Using `!=` instead of `<` is also suspicious to me, because it makes the loop semantically different than the original version, and can lead to some rare, but interesting, bugs.

I would rephrase it as "can **catch** some rare, but interesting, bugs."

One simple way to argue this point was offered by Dijkstra in his book [*A Discipline of Programming*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013215871X). He pointed out that it is easier to reason about loops with stronger post-conditions than it is to reason about loops with weaker post-conditions. Since post-condition of a loop is the inverse of its continuation condition, one should prefer loops with weaker continuation conditions.

`a != b` is weaker than `a < b`, because `a < b` implies that `a != b`, but `a != b` does not imply that `a < b`. Therefore, `a != b` makes a better continuation condition.

In very simple terms, you know that `a == b` immediately after the loop with `a != b` is over; on the other hand, when the loop with `a < b` is over, all you know is that `a >= b`, which is not as good as knowing the exact equality.

Comment: That's pretty academic, though - if you're ever in a situation where `a > b` would lead to post-loop problems, then the continuation condition `a != b` would already have led to an infinite loop.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's exactly the point! An infinite loop has a better chance of attracting your attention than a (slightly) incorrect result of a computation. I think that this specific argument is one of these rare cases when a purely academic argument gives you free, easy-to-follow advise for everyday coding. FWIW, I've been writing loops this way for some 28 years.

Comment: `it matters more when you use iterators` -- It's a sure sign of my inexperience that I didn't think about iterators at all when writing this question. Dijkstra's argument is a fresh one to me. I'm not totally convinced, because while you know that `a == b` immediately after the loop, you don't know that `a` was "within range", for lack of a better phrase. And if you can prove that the loop index can't skip over the value of `b`, shouldn't that also be applicable to `a < b`? Can't argue that an infinite loop is more noticeable than an off-by-one error

Comment: Also, I like the linked Amazon page. "A Discipline of Programming: 59683rd Edition". Sounds like Dijkstra might have needed "A Discipline of Writing" himself :P

Comment: @awksp When you use `!=`, your readers wouldn't have to prove that `a` wouldn't skip over `b`, because you wrote it explicitly in the body of your code. When you write `<`, on the other hand, your readers might need to check the body of your loop for other tricks, such as setting `a` to `MAX_INT` or something equally silly. Using `!=` tells them that there are no tricks; `<` leaves the readers to check for themselves.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying -- when the loop terminates, the value of `a` is known. What I had in mind was making sure `a` didn't overflow/loop around, which, to me, would require reading the body of the code either way. Did I get your point right?

Comment: If you want to be paranoid, then you could add an `assert(! (a > b));` in the loop's block. That way you can catch obscure bugs but can also use the better loop condition.

Comment: 1. There's always another possible way to get out of a loop (which will make reasoning about the post-conditions a lot harder): `break`, `return` and `goto` 2. In many cases, you don't care about the value of `a` after the loop - the loop variable is often scoped. 3. `a < b` and `a != b` are only logically equivalent when you're increasing a in steps of `c` and can make the guarantee that the start value will be lower than the end value and the difference `b-a` will be a multiple of `c` (so your stronger post-condition needs a stronger guarantee on the loop parameters).

Comment: Still if you're implementing a loop like `∑ᵇᵢ₌ₐ fᵢ`, you do want to use `i<b`, otherwise where you should get 0 (when `a>b`), you'll instead get infinite loop.

Comment: also, if you switch the type of the loop variable to floating point (`for(double a = 0.0; a != b; a += 1.0)`), you might find out that `a != b` might never be false

Comment: @hoffmale Comparing FP variables for equality is nearly always a mistake, so no surprise here. An infinite loop resulting from using `!=` helps you find that your assumption of FP behavior was wrong.

Comment: "it matters more when you use iterators" - although since we are talking about premature optimization, you should check that for your compiler with optimizations on, iterators don't just reduce to pointers for which it again does not matter because the post-increment is optimized to a pre-increment.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I know that comparing FP variables for absolute equality is nearly always a mistake. The point of that comment was to show that weakening the loop continuation condition might introduce very subtle "bugs" that can be very hard to reason about (especially for those not too well versed in FP details in this case), maybe harder than about the weaker post-condition.

Comment: @hoffmale Using a floating point as the counter makes it hard for the programmer to know how many times the loop will execute even with `<`.

Comment: @v7d8dpo4: I'm not encouraging using FP counter variables - but I've seen enough code (mostly by more academic people) that used those. Also, I tried to find a rather trivial example that made reasoning about continuation and post-conditions a lot harder (changing a counter variable from int to double by itself doesn't seem that bad of a change on a first glance)

Answer (score 13):

I personally don't like the second one, I would use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i); //A combination of the two :)
```

---

### `int i = 0` vs `int i(0)`

No difference whatsoever, they even compile to the same assembly instructions (no optimizations):

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0; //int i(0);
}
```

`int i = 0` version:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

`int i(0)` version:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

---

### `i < n` vs `i != n`

You are right that the `!=` might introduce some interesting bugs:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
{
    if (i == 2)
        i += 2; //Oops, infinite loop
    //...
}
```

The `!=` comparison is mostly used for iterators, which don't define a `<` (or `>`) operator. Maybe that's what the author meant?

But here, the second version is clearly better, as it more clearly states intent than the other one (and introduces less bugs).

---

### `i++` vs `++i`

For built-in types (and other trivial types), such as `int`, there is no difference, as the compiler will optimize the temporary return values out. Here, again, some iterators are expensive, and so the creation and destruction might be a performance hit.

But that *really* doesn't matter in this case, as even without optimizations they emit the same assembly output!

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    i++; //++i;
}
```

`i++` version:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

`++i` version:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Comment: What about `int i{0}` in the first section of your answer? Will it be different for non-primitive iterator type?

Comment: @Sergey Yes and no, I don't think so. They all both call the constructor (except for `{}`, which would perform aggregate initializing).

Comment: What about  different compilers?

Comment: @M.M I used gcc, but the result will likely be the same for clang and msvc.

Answer (score 7):

The two forms are in no way related to performance. What matters is how you write code in general. Follow similar patterns and focus on expressiveness and conciseness. So for the initialisation, prefer int i(0) (or better: i{0}) as this underlines that this is an initialisation, not an assignment. For the comparison, the difference between != and < is that you put lower requirements on your type. For integers there is no difference, but in general iterators might not support less than, but should always support equality. Finally, prefix increment expresses your intent better because you do not use the result.

Comment: +1 for `i{0}` - this is the real new hotness: all initialization everywhere has the same look now, and is visibly different from assignment.

Comment: The curly initialisation is not just new hotness. It is better because you avoid narrowing conversions to take place.

Answer (score 3):

In this code it makes no difference. But I guess what the writer is aiming for is to use the same style coding style for all of the `for` loops (except range-based ones, presumably).

For example if we had some other class as the loop counter type

```
for ( Bla b = 0; b < n; b++ )
```

then there are problems:

- `Bla b = 0;` may fail to compile if `Bla` does not have an accessible copy/move constructor
- `b < n` may fail to compile if `Bla` does not admit definiig a weak ordering, or define `operator<`.
- `b++` may fail to compile or have unintended side-effects, since post-increment typically returns by value

Using the writer's suggested pattern, the requirements on a loop iterator are lessened.

---

Note that this discussion can go on forever. We could say `int i{};` is better because some types might not admit `0` as initializer.  Then we could say, well what if `n` was not an `int`? It should really be `decltype(n) i{}`. Or in fact we should use a range-based loop which fixes all the above problems. And so on.

So at the end of the day it is still personal preference.

Comment: If an iterator implements postfix operator++, it needs to work correctly when used solely for its side effects.

Answer (score 3):

> i != n

Frankly, slide 8 lost me right there, and you are correct with the suspicion that something might not be quite right.

Aside from the high likelyhood that a modern compiler will have those kinds of loop optimized as thoroughly as it is theoretically possible for current CPUs, encouraging a programmer to write less robust code to "help the optimizer" for *whatever* reason is just very oldfashioned and has no place *at all* in the modern world, IMO. The real cost of software is the human time these days, not the CPU time, for 99.99...% of all projects.

On a meta-level, truisms have no place in coding guidelines. A slide establishing a coding convention without giving objective and well-thought-out reasons for it is useless. Note that I would be OK with a reason like "we do it this way because we want to pick *one* style instead of a plethora", I don't need a technical reason - just *any* reason. I can then decide whether I accept the reasoning behind the coding guideline or not (and thus accept the guideline itself).

Answer (score 0):

It is *stylistically* better to use postfix increment/decrement in C-style `for` loops whenever this is possible,

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

rather than

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

With a postfix operator, the loop variable `i` appears on the left-hand side of all three expressions, which makes the code easier to read.  Also, if you need to step by any value other than 1, you have to write it with the `i` on the left ...

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
```

so for consistency's sake it should also be done that way when you are using the `++` shorthand for `+= 1`.  (As pointed out in the comments, we might find it easier to read `+= 1` than `++` if we didn't have 45 years of convention teaching us `++`.)

With fundamental types like `int`, prefix/postfix increment will make no performance difference; as other answers have demonstrated, the compiler will generate exactly the same code either way.  With iterators, the optimizer has to do more work to get it right, but I don't think there's any excuse for a C++11-era compiler that fails to handle postfix operator++ as efficiently as prefix operator++ when they are used solely for their side effects.

(Of course, if you're stuck with an iterator that only supports prefix `++`, then you write it that way.)

Comment: With that logic, why would it not be more consistent and more readable to always do `i += 1`?

Comment: @CodyGray Only because it is traditional to use the increment operators.  If we were starting from scratch, we *would* find it more consistent and readable to write `i += 1` or `i -= 1`.

Comment: There is a huge difference between I += 1 and ++I. For += 1 you need random access iterators, whereas you for ++ only need forward iterators. I know you are talking integer operations here, but the general rule of thumb should be to not use more than the minimal set of requirements needed for your algorithm.

Comment: @user3721426 If it had been customary to write `for (i = 0; i < N; i += 1)` then forward iterators would have been required to support `operator +=` with argument 1.

Comment: How would you implement += 1 and not e.g. += 2? This is not possible in C++, I believe.

Comment: @user3721426 I'm pretty sure you can (ab)use templates somehow to make operator+=(N) refuse to compile unless N==1 (provably at compile time - that would be a feature, not a bug, in this case).