# Python algorithm issue

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a problem with an exercise algorithm, not sure how it works on python. So here it is:

Write program, where you find the time in the worst case where a Person can wait in the post office in condition
that, he will get his package at the same day.He doesn't go in the post office earlier than 08:00.

Input:
On the first row on the standart input there is an integer number N - thats the number of the work intervals of the post workers.

On the next N rows are written the start and end of every work interval in format: HH:MM HH:MM.
The intervals are sorted by time and they don't start earlier than 08:00.Between the neighbour intervals there is 1 minute pause.
On the last row there is an integer number K - thats the time in minutes for searching the package.

Output:

On one row of the standart output the program should print the worst case
 that the Person waited in the post office - time of entering the office and time of getting the package
Both times should be printed in format HH:MM and to be splitted with one interval(space).
If there is more than one worst cases, to be printed the one where the Person's arrival in the post office is earlier.

Ranges
`1 ≤ N ≤ 20`

Example:
Input 
 `3
 08:00 08:01
 08:02 08:03
 08:04 08:05
 1`

Output 
 `08:01 08:03`

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Analysis of the problem - The exercise is technical, the program realisation should be ran accurate.
You should make every time in minutes like - hours*60+minutes. Then every interval
will be set with couple numbers , where t1 is the start of the interval in
minutes, t2 – end of the interval.
With c – the arrival time for the Person in the post office.
At start c = 480 (the hour is 08:00). We will look the intervals in rows. With i –
the next working interval on time of t1 to t2. If t2 − t1 ≥ K, then the Person will get
his package in moment t1 + K, and he was waiting t1 + K – с minutes. Compare it with
the found one for this moment, and if that option is better, we save it. Then we apply
c = t2 − K + 1 and we go afterwards to make the intervals the same way.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you expect as output?

Comment: Can you provide some more test cases? Also, at least explain one!

Comment: As output - time of entering the office and time of getting the package

Comment: "I need to understand how this works" => you wrote the code but don't understand how it works ??? That's a problem indeed...

Comment: well the "for" in python is different than c++ and I don't actually think i wrote it correct in python

Comment: The output in your example `Output 08:01 08:03` says time of entering to the office is `08:01` right? Why isn't it `08:00`? Also, "for" in Python is just like the [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3648965/6900838) in C++. When you use range(), it almost same the normal for loop in C++.

Comment: Because the person doesn't go in the post earlier than 08:00 , he can go in 09:00 for example. Look the inputs, they are the work intervals of the post workers.

Comment: I think you need to go back and study the basics. You even admit that you're not certain you wrote the for loop properly. I'm looking at this code and I can't see how it'd run. You initialise a list with one element, but then you loop over it for some arbitrary length without appending new elements. This will give you an `IndexError`. And what's up with `day[i].h1` and the likes???

Comment: @mastaofthepasta So, how can we know **the worst case that the Person waited in the post office** without knowing the time he go? Also, if the person doesn't go in the post earlier than 08:00, the time of entering to the office can be 08:00.

Comment: @Alperen  he goes in the office not earlier than 08:00, so I guess its 08:00, dunno about that

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: You've just made it a lot worse for you. You removed your code, no matter how flawed, and now the question reads like a homework question without even showing your working. Please read the FAQ on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what topics you can ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the user have to give **the time of entering**. So, I added it to inputs.

Here is my code:

```
# Translates HH:MM to minutes as integers. For example 08:00 => 480
def str2minutes(s):
    sp = s.split(":")
    return int(sp[0]) * 60 + int(sp[1])

# Translates minutes to HH:MM. For example 490 => 08:10
def minutes2str(m):
    hour = int(m / 60)
    minute = m - hour * 60
    if hour < 10: 
        hour = "0" + str(hour)
    if minute < 10: 
        minute = "0" + str(minute)
    return str(hour) + ":" + str(minute)

# Get interval count(N)
interval_count = int(input("Enter work intervals N : "))

# Get intervals separately
interval_list = []
for i in range(interval_count):
    interval_list.append(input("Enter hours and minutes : "))

# Get searching time(K)
searching_time = int(input("Enter the time in minutes for searching the package K : "))

# I think, getting time of entering is necessary
time_of_entering = input("Enter the time of entering : ")

# Control all intervals until find the proper one
for interval in interval_list:
    start =  str2minutes(interval.split()[0])
    finish = str2minutes(interval.split()[1])
    if start >= str2minutes(time_of_entering) and (finish - start) >= searching_time:
        print("Time of entering : " + time_of_entering)
        print("Time of starting to search : " + minutes2str(start))
        print("Time of getting the package : " + minutes2str(start + searching_time))
        break # If we found the proper one, loop should end.
```

Input:

```
Enter work intervals N : 4
Enter hours and minutes : 08:00 08:01
Enter hours and minutes : 08:10 08:12
Enter hours and minutes : 08:16 08:20
Enter hours and minutes : 08:24 08:30
Enter the time in minutes for searching the package K : 3
Enter the time of entering : 08:01
```

Output:

```
Time of entering : 08:01
Time of starting to search : 08:16
Time of getting the package : 08:19
```

Maybe this not exactly what you want, but I hope, this helps.

Comment: for some reason i don't get the outputs :<

Comment: Can you try again, I edited it

Comment: Yes, its ok now! Thanks for the comments too!