# foreach in C++ int array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am new to C++ and I am writing the following code.
I needed to iterate over all the addons in my calling function - `testFunction`. I know this works in C#, but this code is not working. Can anyone please point out the right way to do it in C++?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"

int testFunction(char* tester);
int _tmain()
{
    int mainProd=2;
    int Addons[]={7,8,9,10};

    testFunction(mainProd,Addons);


}
void testFunction(int mainProd,int addons[])
{
    for(int x = 0 ; addons.length;++x) ---- Not working 
    {
        std::cout<< addons[x];
    }
}
```

---

I tried to implement vector as below suggestions by you guys

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"
#include <vector>

void testFunction(std::vector<int> addons);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    std::vector<int>  Addons ;
    for(int i = 0 ;i<10;++i)
    {
        Addons.push_back(i);
    }
     testFunction(Addons);
}

void testFunction(std::vector<int> addons)
{
    for(int i =0 ; i<addons.size();++i)
    {
        std::cout<<addons.at(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `.length` would work? Perhaps you need to pick [a better book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: What does your favourite C++ book say?

Comment: fordward declare the correct version of testFunction too.

Comment: pass by reference the vector in order to avoid unnecessary copys `void testFunction(const std::vector<int> &addons) // note the 'const' and the '&'`

Comment: `for(int i =0 ; i<addons.size();++i)` is bad style for iterating over a vector. Use `begin` and `end` instead.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain *is bad style* this argument has never convinced me. Is there a better one for this case (when we are not considering to use another contain than std::vector)? Note that C++11 does away with `begin` and `end` when using the range loop `for(auto i:addons)`.

Comment: @Walter C++11 doesn't do away with it; I for one think the range-for is horrible. It's mildly more efficient to use iterators directly for vectors, and significantly more efficient for other containers. Overall though, it is consistent. You can rip out your `std::vector` and use a `std::list` or `std::set` and have code that still works.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Yes, I know this argument (as alluded to in my previous comment), it's much better than *bad style*. Btw, I didn't say C++11 does away with `begin` and `end` -- read my comment carefully!

Comment: Since you are using C++11, you can create your vector using list initialization: `std::vector<int> Addons = {7,8,9,10};`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An array (a raw array) decays into a pointer when passed as an argument to a function, so your array has no size information.

You need to pass the length of the array explicitly into the function to know it inside the function.

Alternatively, and better, use a `std::vector` and then you'll have the `.size()` always available when needed.

Comment: Or `std::array` if the size is fixed at compile-time.

Comment: Because you have an function with a `char*` parameter declared before your main and only defined the correct one after.  http://ideone.com/2H1xX8

Comment: or pass an array by reference

Answer (score 7):

Apart from using vectors, as Tony suggests, you can use templates and pass the array by reference so that the compiler will deduce the array's size:

```
template<int N>
void testFunction(int mainProd,int (&addons)[N])
{
    for(int x = 0; x < N; ++x) // ---- working 
    {
        std::cout<< addons[x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using concepts of C# in C++ but, even if we assume that both languages are similar, they're not equal.

The syntax for a ranged-for in C++ is [the following](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#for):

```
for (type identifier : container) // note the ':', not ';'
{
    // do stuff
}
```

You can use this for *flavour* if you have a [C++11 compiler](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport).

Btw, it seems that you're using properties on your code:

```
for(int x = 0 ; addons.length;++x) // what is lenght?
{
    std::cout<< addons[x];
}
```

There's no such thing in C++, if you want to call an object method you need to call it as a function:

```
// assuming that the object 'addons' have a method
// named 'length'  that takes no parameters
addons.length();
```

But the `addons` variable isn't an object, is an array (take a look to [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)), so it doesn't have a method or property named `length`; if you need to know its length in order to iterate it you can use in some contexts the `sizeof` operator (see the tutorial for more information).

Let's suppose that `addons` were a container:

```
typedef std::vector<addon> Addons;
Addons addons;
```

If you want to iterate it using the C++11 range-for, you can write it as follows:

```
for (addon a : addons)
{
    // do stuff with a.
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: There are a lot of typos in this answer.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain could you help me to fix it? i don't found any typos, maybe you're referring to my lack of english skills?

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use a `std::vector` or `std::array`, you could use `std::foreach`,

```
std::vector<int> addons = {7,8,9,10};
std::array<int, 4> addons = {7,8,9,10}; // Only use one of these...
std::foreach(addons.begin(), addon.end(), [](int i) {
    std::cout << i
});
```

Comment: The lambda should take int, not an iterator

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan My mistake, sorry.

Comment: Might as well use the new range-for then.

Comment: @MarcGlisse You could, but I don't like the syntax; not as readable.

Comment: `std::foreach` vs `range-for` [could be a matter of taste](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047414/advantages-of-stdfor-each-over-for-loop)?

Comment: A raw array will also work with `std::begin()` and `std::end()`. (Not that I would recommend using raw arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Code is working with this

for (int i = 0; i < (end(array) - begin(array)); i++)

Return maximum size

Test whether array is empty

```
array::empty
```

Element of array

```
array::size
```

Array size

```
sizeof()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any STL container, you just need to pass the array by reference to the function. Problem here is that you can't define such argument without exact size of the array. This restriction you can overcome making the function as a template, defining the size as the template parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
void testFunction(int mainProd,int (&addons)[N])
{
    for(int x = 0 ; x < N; ++x)
    {
        std::cout<< addons[x];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int mainProd=2;
    int Addons[]={7,8,9,10};

    testFunction(mainProd,Addons);
    return 0;
}
```