# Add a constant to one sub-element of all elements of an std::vector

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, stl

after looking around on stackoverflow I found this elegant solution

```
transform(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), myvec.begin(),
          bind2nd(std::plus<double>(), 1.0));
```

to add a constant to all the elements of an std::vector containing doubles.
Now that I'm working with keypoints (opencv Keypoints) I have an `std::vector<cv::keypoints>`

These keypoints contain many elements like Pt(location in x,y), size, angle etc...
I want to add a constant to all Pt which in turn are also containing two other paramters (x and y)

I tried to do

```
std::transform( keypoints1.pt.x.begin(), keypoints1.pt.x.end(), 
               keypoints1.pt.x.begin(), std::bind2nd( std::plus<double>(), myconstantX ) );
```

But this doesn't compile. Unfortunately I'm not very comfortable with complex access to STL structures.

Do you have an idea how this can be done without using a for loop?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can do it using a generic foreach loop like this:

```
for (auto& pt : keypoints) {
  pt.x += myconstantX;
}
```

This is far less typing than your version with `std::transform`, and easier to understand, and just as efficient.

Comment: Suppose I find this easier to read than the `for_each` and/or `std::transform` version (which I do). Is there any circumstance where I would still want to use `for_each` or `std::transform`?

Comment: @Nemo: I'm sure we can invent some circumstanes where an STL algorithm might be better.  But I don't have any immediately in mind, so perhaps we can agree to KISS and look to the STL stuff someday if we really can't use the simple way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a modification in-place, it's better for you to use `std::for_each` rather than `std::transform`, as the purpose of transform is to store the results of an operation applied to a collection in another collection.

As for what to apply, if you're using C++11, the simplest way is to use a lambda function for this:

```
std::for_each( keypoints1.begin(), keypoints1.end(), [](cv::keypoint& k) {
     k.pt.x += 1.0;
});
```

However, this is not fundamentally different from a for loop. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047414/advantages-of-stdfor-each-over-for-loop) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, cv::KeyPoint is a structure that contains cv::Point as a field. Since the code that solve the problems should look like this below:

```
std::for_each( keypoints1.begin(), keypoints1.end(), [](cv::KeyPoint & k) {
     k.pt.x += 1.0;
});
```