# How to initialize a vector of distinct dynamically allocated addresses

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Is it possible to create a `std::vector<T*> vec;` during initialization, such that each element of `vec` stores a distinct address on the heap?

Simply doing

```
int N = 10;
std::vector<T*> vec(N, new T)
```

makes all elements of vec store the same address on the heap. Of course, I could simply just do

```
int N = 10;
std::vector<T*> vec(N);
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto &ptr){
  ptr = new int;
});
```

Is there any way to do it from within the constructor call?

Comment: `Is there any way to do it from within the constructor call? ` Nope.

Comment: I can envision a custom iterator, a la `istream_iterator`, that would manufacture an object with `new` each time it's dereferenced. Then you can use a `vector` constructor taking a pair of iterators. Way more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors that fill values into the vector all create duplicates of a single value, so they wont work in this case.

You can do a little better than `std::for_each` though. Since you want each element in the vector filled in with the result of a function, `std::generate` (or `std::generate_n`) is clearly a better fit:

```
std::vector<T *> vec(N);
std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] { return new int; });
```

That said, a vector of raw pointers is most likely a mistake, so I'd recommend exploring other options.

Comment: I have not used `std::generate` before. Why is it better than `std::for_each` in this case? Also, by other options do you mean `std::unique_ptr<int>`?

Comment: @Iamanon: `std::generate` is better because it's more specific. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2050763/179910 Other options would include a `unique_ptr` as well as a [boost `ptr_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).